# Golang MongoDB Import issue

Tags: mongodb, go

Facing issue importing golang mongodb driver.

```
  go get -u go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo
  go get -u go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo@~1.0.0
```

**package go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo: unrecognized import path "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo" (https fetch: Get https://go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo?go-get=1: dial tcp: lookup go.mongodb.org:
 no such host)**

Comment: Seems like a network issue where DNS is not resolving hostname "go.mongodb.org". Can you clarify the question by providing your network environment (behind a firewall, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the mgo library.

```
import (
    mgo "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)
```

You can find more information about this library here: https://gopkg.in/mgo.v2

I used it for multiple websites and it worked like a charm every time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a network issue. Try some another network connection which is not ruled under firewall.

Or else you can use go mod to resolve dependencies automatically.

I am also using the same driver for mongo DB and it is working perfectly fine.

Kindly check here - [Golang-Mongo-Driver-Example](https://github.com/rosspatil/Golang-Mongo-Driver-Example)